# margin attribute converted to selector because of stylus

Tags: css, select, rendering, stylus

I am writing **stylus**  CSS:

```
.list 
  padding 10px
  .container
    margin 10px
    padding 10px
    button
      font-size 20px
```

The expected render is :

```
.list {
  padding:10px;
}
.list .container{
   margin 10px;
   padding :10px;
}
.list .container button{
     font-size:20px;
}
```

However , i got the margin rendered  as SELECTOR!!!!!

```
.list {
  padding:10px;
}
.list .container margin 10px{ /* -- !!11111!!!!???!1111*/
   padding :10px;
}
.list .container button{
     font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code: [link](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=.list%20%0A%20%20padding%2010px%0A%20%20.container%0A%20%20%20%20margin%2010px%0A%20%20%20%20padding%2010px%0A%20%20%20%20button%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%2020px)

Comment: You might be missing a space right before the `margin` property. Like [**this**](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=.list%20%0A%20%20padding%2010px%0A%20%20.container%0A%20%20%20margin%2010px%0A%20%20%20%20padding%2010px%0A%20%20%20%20button%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%2020px)

Comment: Are you sure that you are using same indentation style (spaces/tabs) for this code? Try to configure your editor to show invisible characters to check it.